# Number of permutations with every item out of place

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know how many ways you can arrange the first n numbers so that 1 isn’t the first, 2 isn’t the second etc.

Comment: This is called a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are known as [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), and an easy way to enumerate them is via [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  The number of permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that fixes the points in $S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ (and possibly more points) is $(n-|S|)!$, and we include-exclude over all subsets $S$, giving
$$
\sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}} (-1)^{|S|} (n-|S|)!.
$$
Since the summand only varies with $|S|$, this is equal to
\begin{align*}
 & \sum_{s=0}^n (-1)^s \binom{n}{s} (n-s)! \\
={} & n!\sum_{s=0}^n \frac{(-1)^s}{s!}.
\end{align*}
There's many other formulas for this on the Wikipedia page.